# Cannot use the IMSL Numerical library(location of the license file)

Tags: imsl

I am trying to use the IMSL library.
But I keep getting the following error.

The location of the license file cannot be determined.
Use the environmental variable IMSL_LIC_FILE to specify the pathname to the license file.

I added environmental variable as follows.

%IMSL_LIC_FILE%\C:\Program Files (x86)\RogueWave\license\imsl_eval

But I am still getting the same error message.
Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might refer to a piece of help documentation, which is typically set in "C:...\RogueWave\imsl\fnl-2021.0.0(version of IMSL)\win100in212x64(env number)\notes\README.txt"[This is my own location of the student-licensed limited version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPhe8.png)